# Unit testing in Docker image in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my `PR` pipeline with the following stages, one being dependent on the previous one:

1. `Changed`: basically determines what services have changed so it ignores testing and buildings ones that haven't.
2. `UnitTesting`: installs services into agent pool and runs the unit tests *if* the services have changes to them.
3. `BuildAndPush`: builds and pushes the `test-<version>` image to ACR if unit tests are passing.
4. `IntegrationTesting`: honestly haven't figured this out yet, but it should pull all the images and deploy them somehow.
5. `SeleniumTesting`: same as 4.

Anyway, I had `UnitTesting` before `BuildAndPush` because I figured it was the quickest way to determine if a build is failing by cutting out the the time of building the image.

It is quicker:

- `UnitTesting` one service takes about 1.5 minutes. The bulk of that is `npm install` and `npm build`. The tests themselves are only about 10-15 seconds.
- `BuildAndPush` one service takes about 2.25 minutes, but that doesn't including the testing portion.

That being said I feel like the `UnitTesting` stage adds an additional 1.25 minutes per service that really isn't necessary: just `BuildAndPush` and unit test the image would actually be faster overall for the pipeline. The developer would know if the build is failing still well under 5 minutes.

So that is what I can't figure out:

How do you run unit tests in a Docker image in an Azure Pipeline?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you run unit tests in a Docker image in an Azure Pipeline?

Since [Docker volumes are not supported when building a container](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14080). We need to add task to build the image via below script, including running the unit tests, and the copiying the test results file from the container to a folder on the build server. We use the Docker Copy command to do this:

```
docker build -f ./WebApplication1/Dockerfile --target build -t webapplication1:$(build.buildid) . 
docker create -ti --name testcontainer webapplication1:$(build.buildid) 
docker cp testcontainer:/src/WebApplication1.UnitTests/TestResults/ $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testresults 
docker rm -fv testcontainer
```

When you create a ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio and add Docker support for it you will get a Docker file that looks something like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base 
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 80 
EXPOSE 443 

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build 
WORKDIR /src 
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"] 
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" 
COPY . . 
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1" 
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

FROM base AS final 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=publish /app . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

If we want to build and run the tests inside the container, we need to extend the Docker file. For example, add a XUnit test project called WebApplication1.UnitTests.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base 
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 80 
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build 
WORKDIR /src 
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"] 
COPY ["WebApplication1.UnitTests/WebApplication1.UnitTests.csproj", "WebApplication1.UnitTests/"] 
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" 
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1.UnitTests/WebApplication1.UnitTests.csproj" 
COPY . . 
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app 
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.UnitTests/WebApplication1.UnitTests.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

RUN dotnet test "WebApplication1.UnitTests/WebApplication1.UnitTests.csproj" --logger "trx;LogFileName=webapplication1.trx" 

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

FROM base AS final 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=publish /app . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Then add task Publish Test Results to publish the test result.

You could check these blogs for more details:

> [We start the container with unit tests in Azure DevOps (VSTS)](https://sudonull.com/post/7902-We-start-the-container-with-unit-tests-in-Azure-DevOps-VSTS)

> [Running .NET Core Unit Tests with Docker and Azure Pipelines](https://blog.ehn.nu/2019/01/running-net-core-unit-tests-with-docker-and-azure-pipelines/)

Comment: When you run `dotnet publish`, what determines where it finds `WebApplication1.csproj`? Shouldn't the working directory still be `/src` and all the project files be in folders?

Comment: But what happens if the tests fail? the image is not going to be built, and therefore the docker create and docker ps commands cannot be done, how are the results published if the docker build fails?

Comment: Will the Docker@2 task not work on this?